# JQuery jTable - append records to existing records with load action

Tags: jquery, jquery-jtable

I have a jTable where records can be added manually (with button), but they can also be added through action.

I have button for adding new user and a check box for adding all users on task - in that case, 'load' method of jTable is triggered. (when checkbox is checked)

My problem is that if I have already added several users manually (with button) and then want to add all users (through load action), load action updates jTable completely, thus deleting existing users.

What I would like to do is add all users to existing users if there are some already in the table. Is this possible?

Comment: sounds like you may not be storing the new users on the server and the refresh from the server doesn't have them, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

How are you adding you records manually? If you manipulating the DOM to display more rows, you are fighting with jTable. Use the jTable method `addRecord` http://jtable.org/ApiReference/Methods#met-addRecord to have jTable do the work for you, and both the table and the database will be updated.

Note. if you set the `clientOnly` property to true on the `addRecord` call, you will have the same problem